# C++ calculate time difference between 2 strings with time zone

Tags: c++

I need to check the difference between 2 strings timestamp in c++. the timestamp contains the time zone (%Z) variable in it.

I used the diff time function to get difference

In short this is the code i tried:

```
    string current = "2021-02-17 11:26:55 +04";
    string old = "2021-02-17 11:26:56 +02";

    cout<<current<<endl;
    cout<<old<<endl;


    struct tm currentTime, reqTime;
    strptime(current.c_str(), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %Z", &currentTime);
    strptime(old.c_str(), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %Z", &reqTime);

    double seconds = difftime(mktime(&currentTime), mktime(&reqTime));
```

the codes give a 1 second difference between the 2 times. but it doesn't consider the difference in time zone.

How can I get the difference taking into consideration the time zone (in this example the difference is 2 hours and 1 second

or how can I manually transform both time to GMT and then do the difference

EDIT:

To get current date i used the following:

```
string currentDateTime() {
    time_t     now = time(0);
    struct tm  tstruct;
    char       buf[80];
    tstruct = *localtime(&now);
    strftime(buf, sizeof(buf), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %Z", &tstruct);

    return buf;
}
```

Comment: assuming you're on Linux I don't think your time zone matches the format for either `%Z` or `%z`: https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strptime.3.html

Comment: @AlanBirtles i edited the question to show how i get the current time. it prints the string i used in the code above

Comment: went through the link you sent apparently %Z has no field in the tm (correct me if I am wrong) so i think i should manually deduct/add TZ difference

Comment: you'd be better off using https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date than the rather loosely specified and platform specific time zone support of `strptime`

Comment: Provided `strptime` is supported, you should use `%z` instead of `%Z` to process delta from UTC (`%Z` is for zone names)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can easily be done in C++20.  Unfortunately this part of C++20 isn't yet shipping.  However there exists a [free, open-source, header-only preview of this part of C++20](https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date) that can be used with C++11/14/17.

```
#include "date/date.h"
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

std::chrono::seconds
diff(std::string const& current, std::string const& old)
{
    using namespace std;
    using namespace std::chrono;
    using namespace date;

    istringstream in{current + " " + old};
    in.exceptions(ios::failbit);
    sys_seconds tp_c, tp_o;
    in >> parse("%F %T %z", tp_c) >> parse(" %F %T %z", tp_o);
    return tp_c - tp_o;
}

int
main()
{
    using date::operator<<;
    std::cout << diff("2021-02-17 11:26:55 +04",
                      "2021-02-17 11:26:56 +02") << '\n';
}
```

Above, `sys_seconds` is defined as a UTC time stamp with seconds precision.  When this type is parsed with `%z`, the offset is applied to the parsed local time in order to obtain the UTC value.  Then you can just subtract them.

This program outputs:

```
-7201s
```

To port this program to C++20, remove:

- `#include "date/date.h"`
- `using namespace date;`
- `using date::operator<<;`